# How to retrieve other information automatically when i enter employee ID

Tags: database

I have a table `Helmet_table` with columns:

```
SLNO, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME,EMPLOYEE ID, HELMET CODE, REMARKS
```

I have created a form linking with drop down for all the columns of form and named as `Helmet_form`. Now when I click on drop down of `EMPLOYEE ID`, I can see all my `EMPLOYEE ID`'s of the table. It's working fine.

However, I wanted that when I enter employee id of any one employee, all his information on the rest of the columns should pop out automatically.

I am learning database all by myself and has limited knowledge. Please help me

Comment: You basically want to Select all from "Helmet_table" where Employee ID = xx

Answer (score 0):

You need read data of that particular employee from Helmet_table table. For that read you can use select statement as shown below

```
select * from Helmet_table where `EMPLOYEE ID`= employee's_id
```

for `employee's_id` you should enter employee id of the selected employee